# Android softkeyboard shows (A -Z) text with(1-9) digits after giving input type ="numberpassword"

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have one quesiton with me.

I am trying to find the answer but no success.

1-I have one `editpasswordfield` in which i can give only numeric password.

i did like this

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"/>
```

and its showing the keyboard number with text.
[image]

but i need the keyboard like this

[image]

i tried this

```
android:inputType="numberPassword|number"
```

and many possibilities but does not worked for me .

if i try `android:inputType="number"`.It works but my field is password so this does not work its visible to user.

any help.

Comment: That text will not be a problem.Because when the user press a button only integer will be given as input.And that text will be helpful for some users to remember their password! Thats why android provided text  next to integer, if input type is "numberPassword"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Hope this helps....